# setting up broadcast Receiver to turn on bluetooth

Tags: android, bluetooth, broadcastreceiver, powermanager

I'm a newbie in both Java and Android and I'm trying to figure out how to do the following action. Btw, I find that the official Google Android documentation is NOT for newbies and would like any referral to something a bit more... non-native programmer friendly.

Ok, here goes:

I would like to turn on/off Bluetooth automatically when I plug in/unplug the phone - pc or ac.

So, I have found the following components:

BatteryManager: Seems like using the `ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED` intent is the way to go, and setting up a broadcast receiver for when this changes. Is it correct?

I've also found BluetoothAdapter and within that, there's the enable() method. Which says: "do not use without explicit user action to turn on Bluetooth." - is plugging in the phone a explicit user action? Is this the right thing for me to use? The same goes for disable(), of course.

Also, the `BroadcastReceiver`s I've seen examples for in the Internet(s) only show me how to launch an intent - usually to open a new activity. I assume I can have the Broadcast Receiver launch a method in which I will turn bluetooth on and off? Can an intent be a method, and not just activity?

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> BatteryManager: Seems like using the ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED intent is the way to go, and setting up a broadcast receiver for when this changes. Is it correct?

Yes, that is one way to monitor things like when a charger has been connected (including plugging to a USB port with charge capability). You can also use `ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED`.

> is plugging in the phone a explicit user action?

NO - most definitely not unless you create a pop-up asking for the user's consent. To quote the docs for the `enable()` method...

> **Bluetooth should never be enabled without direct user consent.** If you want to turn on Bluetooth in order to create a wireless connection, **you should use the ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE Intent, which will raise a dialog that requests user permission to turn on Bluetooth**. The enable() method is provided only for applications that include a user interface for changing system settings, such as a "power manager" app.

When I plug my device to charge, 9 times out of 10 I don't want it to do anything but charge. If I had your app installed on my phone and found out it was enabling Bluetooth silently and without my knowledge, your app would be un-installed straight away.

There are known security issues with Bluetooth and, depending on user settings, you could put somebody's device at risk if it is enabled without their knowledge.

> Can an intent be a method, and not just activity?

No, an `Intent` is part of a messaging system. See [Intents and Intent Filters](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/intents/intents-filters.html). Yes, I know it's not very 'newbie-friendly' but Android is a complex beast and if you really want to program successfully for it you've got to read this sort of stuff.

Comment: Hi MisterSquonk, thanks for the reply :) I understand your point about not wanting to do it silently, but that won't apply with my app - it'll be an extremely simply app - all it will do is turn bluetooth on and off. so, if you download and install it, you know what you're getting. So, it doesn't sound like there's a way to turn on/off in the background, without a dialog, huh? Juice Defender has this option, but it doesn't work VERY well. Also, to be clear, i'm not afraid of reading a lot, it's just that 4 out of 5 times, i don't understand their explanation ;)

Comment: I find "never" a very strong word :) We **are** enabling Bluetooth without direct user consent because we have a professional driver's application, and it needs to stay ON all the time, regardless of what the user does. I'm glad the Android designers allowed us to programmatically force-enable Bluetooth, or else our app would fail in the real world :)